# IC datasheet finding

Tags: mosfet, integrated-circuit

Dear all I have an IC marked as 4N0409GAB609. ANd I know it is a MOSFET. But I could not find its datasheet on google. Can anyone help me in finding the details of this IC?
[image]

Comment: I'm not even going to play because the first link on google when I searched was for the datasheet. "Does not show any research effort".

Comment: I have also searched but didn't find anything. can you share the link you found?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could be a IPG20N04S4-09 from Infineon. Chip type and Chip marking do not always match. In your case the chip marking (designator) is just 4N0409, the GAB609 is probably some production identifier.